# pip freeze takes 26s

Tags: python, performance, pip

`pip freeze` and `install` and so on takes very long (26s) as root user but just a second as normal user.

`sudo python -v -m pip freeze` shows a long waiting between following both lines

```
import keyrings.alt.file # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keyrings/alt/file.pyc 
import Crypto # directory /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Crypto
```

which module is that? pycrypt? I'm on 2.6.1 so its the latest...

I would expect the same time behavior as normal user

Comment: Do you have any environment variables set as root ? `env | grep pip`

Comment: No I dont 
root@host:/home/iwetzel#  env | grep pip
LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
root@host:/home/iwetzel#